# Is there a method to obtain Mammout Coin without buy them?

Tags: brawlhalla

I'm playing Brawlhalla since a year but I don't have many skins or reactions cause I never bought anything. So, is there a method to obtain some Mammout Coins in order to get a crate without buy them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

The only way to obtain Mammoth coins is to spend your IRL dollars on them.

If you don't feel like paying for just the coins, most DLC packs come with a set amount of Mammoth coins including their exclusive contents. These packs are also giftable, so if you have a generous friend, there's always a chance they decide to give you it as a gift. The coins are still being bought, but at least you are getting them for free ;)

Edit: I also wouldn't put it past the developers to offer mammoth coins as a [Viewership Reward](https://brawlhalla.gamepedia.com/Brawlhalla_Viewership_Rewards). This is currently not the case, but who knows.